# Как найти chat_id из пересланного сообщения Telegram

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно каким-то образом найти chat_id пересланного сообщения с помощью библиотеки Telebot в Python. Пытался обращаться через message.forward_from но выдаёт всегда None. Как нужно обратиться, чтоб найти chat_id

Answer (score 0):

Удивительно, но все оказалось очень просто, надо обращаться через message.forward_from_chat